# python infinite loop getting slowdown while getting data from other text file

Tags: python, text

I am new to python,actually I tried a simple program. I am reading a text file which is updating data every time from logs so I need to copy or append that updated data only from that text file to another text file and do some process.For this I am done with below code.

```
with open("Log.txt") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
i=len(data)#find length of file
def check(i):
    with open("Log.txt") as f2:
        count=f2.readlines()
        x=len(count)#finds length of file after update
        print(x)
        j=i
        i=x
        while(j<x):
            with open("Log.txt") as f1:
                count=f1.readlines()
                msg=count[j]#get updated text
                j=j+1
                with open('Output1.txt', 'a') as f3:
                    f3.write(str(msg))#append updated text to file
        process()#calling a function which do some process on text file

while True:
    check(i)
```

By using above code I am getting updated data but the problem is its getting slow down while doing infinite loops.Means Initially  If I have a data in Log.text file upto 12:00pm it will append all data,After looping for 5 min the data in log.text file will increase but after same 5 min time I will get only 3 min data into output file. it was slow there is so much delay in getting data from text file.why??how can I get same updated text into output file instantly.

Comment: Can you provide more details? As to what process() is doing. A possible reason might be file handler still remaining open and data written to file keeps of buffering in memory. You can use `f3.flush()` to commit the data to disk even if your buffer is small.

Comment: you can try `with open("Log.txt") as f1:` followed by `while(j<x):`. see if it improves! also, you're not closing the files.. same file you're opening multiple times as well!

Comment: @VanPeer The syntax `with open('file') as f:` handles  automaticaly the closing of the file when the loop is exited

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
def read_and_copy():
    with open("/var/log/messages") as input:
        with open('/tmp/output', 'a+') as output:
            while True:
                # read line by line
                data = input.readline()
                # check if line is not empty
                # also if needed - provide necessary checks
                if data:
                    # write to another file
                    output.write(data)  
                    # Flush the write buffers of the stream if applicable.
                    # This does nothing for read-only and non-blocking streams.
                    output.flush()  




read_and_copy()
```

Keep in mind, that each call of `read_and_copy` will read entire file again and overwrite output file.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should use is `follow`, which follows a file. Whenever new lines are added to `Log.txt`, the below code updates it to `Output1.txt`.

Try this

```
import os, time

logfile = "Log.txt"
thefile = open(logfile)

def follow(thefile):
    thefile.seek(0,2)       # Go to the end of the file
    while True:
        line = thefile.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(1)   # Sleep briefly
        else:
            with open('Output1.txt', 'a') as f3:
                f3.write(line)

loglines = follow(thefile)
```